# How to display entire content in Text box(UI) when tab is pressed in IE

Tags: html, css

When the name is entered in `<input>` element of (maxlength= 40) and given length is just = 20 (5 alphabets and followed by 20 empty spaces) and I press tab to next input element, In Chrome I'm able to see the name displayed but In `IE` it shows the empty spaces in the end and not the alphabets in the front.

Comment: please share your simple code

Comment: its actually confidential which cant be shared. sorry about it.

Comment: I give you a think you use keyup event and check keycode is equal 9 then you get 
accepted actions

Comment: @Md. Abu Sayed when i press tab and go to second <input>, my first <input> element should automatically take "home" key event. I tried setting 36 keycode and since it is read only, i am not able to do it.. can someone help me in this regard.

Comment: you can find my sample answer

Answer (score 0):

**@DevME maybe you locking this answer**

it's work when you keypress the condition when you press tab then get your actions

```js
$('.firstname').keydown(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if(keyCode == 9) {
    $("#display").text('Your Display is : '+ $(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="firstname" type="text" value="" placeholder="first name">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="last name">
 <p id="display">no output</p>
```

**thanks**